# Mathematica's deeper documentation

Tags: documentation

Is there Mathematica documentation on the methods that it uses? Documentation that goes into explanations of the methods that it employs.

Comment: [questions/tagged/implementation-details](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/implementation-details)

Comment: [Some Notes on Internal Implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depends on what you're looking for more information on.  Here are a few advanced guides that give details on implementation in different areas:

- [Advanced Numerical Differential Equation Solving in the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html)
- [Advanced Numerical Integration in the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html)
- [Advanced Topics in Algebra](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedAlgebraOverview.html)
- [Constrained Optimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html)
- [Finite Element Method User Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html)