# Make a ChatGPT-like interface to Mathematica documentation/ this site?

Tags: documentation, user-interface, chatai

It would be great if one could come up with a interface to Mathematica documentation (or possibly this site) in the spirit of ChatGPT?

We have Wolfram alpha to answer direct mathematical questions in plain language but it is not (?) directly interfaced to the language's help system which is becoming a bit big to browse.

At some stage this is a question for Wolfram but...

> can we as a community define the precise requirement of such an interface? Or write a prototype which grep within the documentation?

The output could be as extensive as Wolfram alpha.

In some sense this question is  the opposite of that [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197364/1089) which gives details beyond what is in the (standard) documentation.

It is also the opposite of the [SummarizeDefinition](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SummarizeDefinition/) function

---

To be a bit more specific, sometimes to find information in the documentation you need to know the jargon or specific keyword that was implemented within mathematica. It would therefore be great to have a chatbot which could 'linguistically understand' the concept and find the synonyms which are actually used within the Documentation.

---

**Note added 23/3/23**: it seems some of the issues are addressed [by Wolfram's blog](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/03/chatgpt-gets-its-wolfram-superpowers/) as, I quote, "*chatgpt gets its wolfram superpowers*".

---

**Update**: Mathematica 13.3 provides the answer straight out of the box with a LLM code assistant

[image]

Comment: One of my requirements would be that the answers are correct, both in content and syntax. This seems like a rather high bar to jump at this point.

Comment: @Roman of course that would ideally be the case; but if the learning is done in the documentation and it links to the documentation it will be at best as good as the documentation (?)

Comment: Is this the right site for this question? Maybe the meta site instead?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it takes a decade of research to come up with something such as an AI interface to another software. Questions that are typically posted and answered here are considerably limited in scope.

Comment: @Syed ok; I was just trying to ping WRI on this as an improvement for their Documentation. People on mathematica.SE have been able to produce means of querying the documentation in the past to extract functions which in fact became part of mathematica in later release so...

Comment: I would like to have a simpler feature; being able to track my own documentation usage with a history list. We all remember the time when we started searching for MS Office docs using Google and indeed it got more and more effective over the last 15 years. Something similar for Mathematica would perhaps also become a reality through external means.

Comment: @Syed why don't you write your comment as an answer then? Its a possible improvement that should be easy to implement which would help browsing the document more constructively.

Comment: I would like to draw the attention to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOQV9VakBgE and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5WZhCBRDpU which suggests IMHO that this question was in fact of interest?

Answer (score 9):

> This is not a full answer but a starting point, which illustrates both the **strength** (it looks reasonable) but also the  **strong limitation**  of present day chatbot in producing correct Mathematica code.

Indeed, using

```
  PacletInstall["ChristopherWolfram/OpenAILink"]
  Needs["ChristopherWolfram`OpenAILink`"]
  $OpenAIKey = "<sk-.... your key>"
```

as described  [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/ChristopherWolfram/OpenAILink/),
I can define a new function, `ChatHelp` as

```
ChatHelp[str_] := 
 Normal[PacletSymbol[
    "ChristopherWolfram/OpenAILink", 
     "ChristopherWolfram`OpenAILink`OpenAIChatComplete"][
    PacletSymbol[
     "ChristopherWolfram/OpenAILink", 
        "ChristopherWolfram`OpenAILink`OpenAIChatMessageObject"]
["user", str <> " in Mathematica"]]][[1, 2, 2]]
```

So that we can ask

```
  ChatHelp["hypergeometric functions"]
```

or

```
  ChatHelp["How to do Symbolic Integration?"]
```

which produces

---

### [image]

One can iterate the same query, as in

```
ChatHelp["hypergeometric functions?"]
ChatHelp["hypergeometric functions?"]
```

or provide the chatbot with different details to get different answers; e.g.

```
ChatHelp["How to plot a graph?"]
```

gives a different answer than

```
ChatHelp["How to plot a graph with vertices?"]
```

---

Note that it can answer relatively complex queries such as:

```
ChatHelp["How to solve heat equations in cylindrical coordinates?"]
```

**but the code it produces is not operational**!

[image]

---

If I ask it to tell me about sines and cosines, as in

```
ChatHelp["sines and cosines"]
```

it writes:

---

3. To plot the sine and cosine functions over an interval of -[Pi] 
   to [Pi]:

   Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, -[Pi], [Pi]}]

Output:

[image: sine_cosine_plot]

---

which is plain weird since the link it produces does not exist! It does suggest that the chatbot seems to have learnt from stackexchange outputs given the syntax it uses.

---

> In closing, note that one could use such function to automatically produces tons of apparently appealing, but in practice garbage answers on *mathematica.stackexchange*! **Something to think about**!

May be one solution would be

1. for mathematica/wolfram to **parse and validate** the code before the answer is produced?
2. and/or train the chatbot on the documentation only?

Comment: Several interesting WL solutions generated by ChatGPT in [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2897251) post on the Wolfram Community site.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks! I guess if the WolframPluggin becomes part of mathematica *and*  the answers are full proved by mathematica it would completely answer my question!

Answer (score 7):

In addition to **OpenAILink** in the **Wolfram Paclet Repository** (see answer here by @chris), there is also an option via the **Wolfram Function Repository**. I did not want this answer to get lost in the comments, so here it is.

> [Function **BirdChat** in Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/BirdChat)
> Open a notebook to chat with a cool bird
> Contributed by: Richard Hennigan (Wolfram Research)

and very similar:

> [Function **AIAssistant** in Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AIAssistant/)
> Open a notebook to chat with an AI programming assistant
> Contributed by: Richard Hennigan (Wolfram Research)

First of all, **BirdChat** requires an API key from OpenAI. Storing the API key with

```
SystemCredential["OPENAI_API_KEY"]="key"
```

will make the key persistently available to **BirdChat**. Doc with examples you can find on the page I linked. I just will note that there are different modes. From simple usual expected chat

[image]

to using special prompt and the ChatGPT acting as kernel simulation (example under the "Neat Examples" section):

[image]

Comment: That's neat! I had seen the BirdChat function but misunderstood it's scope! It seems its a good assistant.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, Birdnardo is just as bad in practice: it produces codes which look even better but still do not work! I tried give me an example of NeuMannValue.

Comment: @chris do you expect LLM to give you always correct answer? These are statistical models and it is very early days, it will get better, but as principle one needs to prompt ChatGPT properly to debug and then even maybe self-test which is possible with [OpenAI Wolfram Plugin](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/03/chatgpt-gets-its-wolfram-superpowers). Similar how you do with humans :-) At least how I understand this. [Example of some debugging](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2864179)

Comment: I guess I am an optimist. I find NeuMannValue formulation un intuitive so I was hoping AI would help me  but it seems as confused as I am ! In any case this bird thing is going very well the packaging. At the end of the day is its as good as LLM, which is to say not good enough as far as I can tell. Thanks again!

Comment: In other words, I would argue that your answer is the correct one (it does understand the question and provides some answer), BUT one would need mathematica to full-proof the answer before it can be considered useful.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to clarify what do you mean by "ChatGPT acting as kernel simulation"? I don't really see it from your screenshot.

Comment: @chris the answers produced are by ChatGPT, not kernel, they are just formatted as Out[].

Comment: Ah ok.  I missed the point!

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Hello, does using it require version `13.0`? I get an error when opening it with `12.0`, the output is `Enclose[NotebookObject[BirdChat]`,and then in BirdChat.nb ,when i ask some questions, it returned `ResourceFunction::usermessage: BirdChat::Internal: An unexpected error occurred. Please report this issue ».`

Answer (score 6):

I was prompted to proclaim the paclet ["OpenAIMode"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/OpenAIMode/) here. :)

Here is a related presentation recording:
["OpenAIMode demo"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htUIOqcS9uA).

---

Here is an example of how to find "help" within a Mathematica notebook using ChatGPT:

[image]

If the paclets
["OpenAILink"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/ChristopherWolfram/OpenAILink/)
and
["OpenAIMode"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/OpenAIMode/)
are installed here is the WL code:

```mathematica
Needs["AntonAntonov`OpenAIMode`"]

OpenAIMode[]

SetOptions[OpenAIInputExecuteToText, OpenAITokenLimit -> 120];
```

Here is the OpenAI cell content:

```
How can use Flatten's second argument in Mathematica?
```

---

### Lying with ChaptGPT

> [...] The blog idea sounds controversial enough! (lying sounds strong, confused certainly!)

Using different temperature settings can produce statements that lie -- or are off-topic -- to different degrees:

[image]

Comment: Could you please give a bit more details in your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @chris Is my update providing sufficient level of detail? :) If not, then I will make an extensive blog post titled "When ChatGPT lies about WL functions."

Comment: Could you please specify as well how does one get the chatGPT prompt? The blog idea sounds controversial enough! (lying sounds strong, confused certainly!)

Comment: @chris "Could you please specify as well how does one get the chatGPT prompt? " -- Use "Shit+|" to create a text completion cell; use "Tab" to convert a text completion cell into an image generation cell. (That is pointed out in the [paclet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/OpenAIMode/) details and in the demo video.)

Comment: @chirs "[...] The blog idea sounds controversial enough! (lying sounds strong, confused certainly!)" -- see my update with "lying evidence" (the section "Lying with ChatGPT.")

Comment: Is there any disadvantage in setting up a low temperature?

Comment: Depending on the context -- with low temperature it is easier to hit the "sparsity problem." With higher temperature values the sparsity problem is solved by making things up. I read (in the API documentation) that OpenaAI uses automatic probabilities for translation and transcription if the temperature is put to 0. I am not sure is that also the case for text completion models.