# Calling Bard or ChatGPT from Mathematica to write programs

Tags: function-construction, chatai

I asked [*Bard*](https://bard.google.com/) to "Write Mathematica code for Newton's Method" and it returned

```
  newton[f_, x0_] := Module[{x, i, err},
  x = x0;
  err = 1;
  While[err > 10^-6,
  x = x - f[x]/D[f[x], x];
 err = Abs[x - x0];
 x0 = x;
];
x
]

  f[x_] := x^3 - 2

  x0 = 1

  newton[f, x0]
```

Although the code does not run, I was surprised by this (sometimes it generates absolute gibberish of course).

My question, is there any way for Mathematica to call Bard, ask such a question, return the code and execute it in Mathematica? Even to do it from within Wolfram Cloud would be interesting.

I know that recently a [*Wolfram Alpha plugin was made for ChatGPT*](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/02/what-is-chatgpt-doing-and-why-does-it-work/), so the same for that - is there a way to call ChatGPT from within Mathematica or Wolfram Cloud?

I imagine that these [*Large Language Models - LLMs*](https://www.mlq.ai/what-is-a-large-language-model-llm/) will be able to ingest the entire corpus of all Mathematica commands, examples, publications and code that has ever been written and I wonder if that can be used to train these LLMs to autogenerate code by just asking it.

Comment: The answers on this page https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/282172/86543 seem to answer this question

Comment: @userrandrand: Thanks - seems slightly different than the answer - so I will check both out - thanks for the link!

Comment: The main addition is from the second answer which shows resource functions (that I have not tried)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### PaLM (Bard)

At this point -- 2023-05-23 -- Bard can be used via [PaLM API](https://developers.generativeai.google). One can apply for the waiting list of [PaLM API / MakerSuite](https://makersuite.google.com/waitlist). (Also, see [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Google-Bard-API/m-p/538517).)

Here are the corresponding paclets:

- ["PaLMLink"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/PaLMLink/)
- ["PaLMMode"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/PaLMMode/)

---

### OpenAI (ChatGPT)

> [...] so the same for that - is there a way to call ChatGPT from within Mathematica or Wolfram Cloud?

Yes, see ["OpenAIMode: paclet for interaction w/ OpenAI's GPT & DALL-E via OpenAILink"](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2864162).

---

More links:

- Paclets

  - ["OpenAILink"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/ChristopherWolfram/OpenAILink/)
  - ["OpenAIMode"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/AntonAntonov/OpenAIMode/)
- Videos

  - ["OpenAIMode demo (Mathematica)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htUIOqcS9uA)
  - ["OpenAIMode code generation workflows demo (Mathematica et al.)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGOtCWJgZEs)
  - ["Streamlining ChatGPT code generation and narration workflows (Raku)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mI-oWLz5dYY)

---

Here is a flowchart showing how user input is OpenAI-executed in a notebook to which `OpenAIMode[]` is applied:

[image]

Comment: Excellent - very nice videos - looking forward to trying these out along with the items in the other linked answer - which seems somewhat different.

Comment: @Moo Any feedback is welcome!